# Django 'block' tag with name 'title' appears more than once

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement logic for my website with a title. But have this error - `Django 'block' tag with name 'title' appears more than once`. How do i fix this?

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %} Main {% endblock %}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

In my template **product_list**

```
{% extends 'shop/application.html' %}

{% if category %}
    {% block title %} Product name of category {% endblock %}
{% elif subcategory %}
    {% block title %} Product name of subcategory {% endblock %}
{% endif %}

...
```

How to implement it? Thanks for help!

Comment: You can not use conditionals for block overrides. You should move the logic *in* the block. Like `{% block title %}{% if category %}A{%else %}B{% endif %}{% endblock %}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, omg, it really helped, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template blocks do not look what is outside of that block. If you override the content of a `{% block %}` in an `{% if condition %} ... {% endif %}`, and the condition is `False`, you will still override the block.

You should "inject" the condition in the `{% block ... %}` override, like:

```
{% block title %}
    {% if category %}A{%else %}B{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```